# RecyclerView stops visual updates after entering data in EditText on the same screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx

In a Fragment, there is EditText to perform search and RecyclerView to show results. Initial filling RecyclerView with data works fine but after the first interaction with EditText when you enter data and Soft Keyboard is shown RecyclerView stops updating data visually.
`notifyDataSetChanged() notifyItemRangeRemoved()` adapter methods do not update RecyclerView visually and usage of DiffUtil didn't solved problem. New data is received by adapter but visually RecyclerView not updated **unless** you scroll it manually.
Do you have any ideas or clues why it can happen? Any help appreciated.

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding="@dimen/10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fl_search" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment code:

```
...
        adapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter( object : MyRVClickListener {
                override fun onItemClicked(
                    position: Int,
                    myDAO: MyDAO
                ) {
                  //  My click action                    
                }
            }
        )

        resultListRV = view.rv_results
        layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(activity!!)

        resultListRV?.layoutManager = layoutManager!!

        val divider = DividerItemDecoration(
            resultListRV?.context,
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
        )

        divider.setDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(appContext, R.drawable.divider_hor)!!
        )

        resultListRV?.addItemDecoration(divider)
        resultListRV?.adapter = adapter

        myViewModel.dataList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
...
```

Adapter code:

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(
    val listener: MyRVClickListener
) : ListAdapter<MyDAO, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MyDAO>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: MyDAO,
            newItem: MyDAO
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: MyDAO,
            newItem: MyDAO
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id== newItem.id
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        (holder as SearchItemVH).bind(item, position)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return SearchItemVH(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.search_list_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    inner class SearchItemVH(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var title: TextView = itemView.list_item_tv_title

        fun bind(listItem: MyDAO, position: Int) {
            title.text = listItem.details.description
            itemView.setOnClickListener { listener.onItemClicked(position, listItem) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add code as well

Comment: "unless you scroll it manually", try to get the focus programmatically to the RecyclerView before `notifyDataSetChanged` ..

Comment: @Black4Guy added code. Unfortunately simple request focus method call don't have any effect

Comment: Where's the code updating/changing the data? And where are you calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @JensV I use Diff Util in this example so update / change data is here 
        myViewModel.dataList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }) If I add notifyDataSetChanged there it changes nothing and also it works perfectly fine until i start to enter data in EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments I found a workaround: `recycler.smoothScrollBy(1, 1)` successfully updates recycler after changes. Still don't know original cause of this problem, hope this solution will help if someone will encounter this problem.